# What is the std::iter::Step trait and what is it used for?

Tags: rust

In Rust documentation there's the [Step trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Step.html). How does it work and what is it used for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the tracking issue:

> The `step_by` method makes it possible to step through ranges with arbitrary-sized steps.

https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27741 
https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/42168

Currently it looks like a bit of a mess and it is all unstable to use. The `steps_between` function feels a lot like C++ where it isn't uncommon to compare iterators since in many data structures they are just fat-pointers to some form of array/vector. However it kinda messes up the trait a bit since it only makes sense for some types of collections. For example, a hash map might benefit from the step forward and backward functions, but may be unable to implement `steps_between`. Since the `Iterator` trait already covers a lot of this functionality and there has been no recent activity on the tracking issue, I imagine this will be deprecated and removed.

If you click the [Source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter/range.rs.html#24-183) button in the docs and look at the trait, you can see it is tagged with unstable. The important part is that it lists the issue number.

```
#[unstable(feature = "step_trait", reason = "recently redesigned", issue = "42168")]
pub trait Step: Clone + PartialOrd + Sized {
    // etc
}
```

I can then find the tracking issue for this trait by either adding it to the end of the `https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/{issue number}` url or searching for it in the issues section of the Rust GitHub repository.